# Custom javascript on/off switch can't get to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to make a switch that on click will switch between "ski" and "snowboard"

I feel like the java i have should be working but for some reason nothing happens.

```js
function switch(a,b){
document.getElementById(a).style.display = "none";
document.getElementById(b).style.display = "";}
```

```css
.switch {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
  padding: 2px;
  width:150px;
  height:24px;
  
}

#on {
  float:left;
  display:"";
  width: auto;
  height:20px;
  background-color: rgb(95,170,250);
}

#off {
  float:right;
  display:none;
  width: auto;
  height:20px;
  background-color: rgb(250,50,25);
}
```

```html
      <div class="switch">
            <div id="on" onclick="switch(on,off)">
          Ski
            </div>
            <div id="off" onclick="switch(off,on)">
            Snowboard
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: 1. `switch` is a keyword, you can't use it for function names. 2. java != javascript.

Comment: And on, off need to be passed as strings, not variables like `toggle('on', 'off')` (in case you rename switch to toggle)

Answer (score 2):

There was a few mistakes made firstly you can not use a switch statement as a named function as its a keyword in javascript. Another mistake was you were passing in on and off as a variable not a string so i have changed that for you as well.. try the below:

```js
function changeState(a, b){
   document.getElementById(a).style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById(b).style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

```css
.switch {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
  padding: 2px;
  width:150px;
  height:24px;
  
}

#on {
  float:left;
  display:"";
  width: auto;
  height:20px;
  background-color: rgb(95,170,250);
}

#off {
  float:right;
  display:none;
  width: auto;
  height:20px;
  background-color: rgb(250,50,25);
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
     <div id="on" onclick="changeState('on','off')">
        Ski
     </div>
     <div id="off" onclick="changeState('off','on')">
            Snowboard
     </div>
</div>
```